# Lilypond: Boxed rehearsal marks with rounded corners

Tags: lilypond

I'm typesetting a piece which has circular rehearsal marks.

[image]

That's easy enough to achieve in lilypond with

```
\set Score.rehearsalMarkFormatter = #format-mark-circle-numbers
```

However, later in the score, the numbers get big and that causes the circle radius to become comically large.

[image]

[Lilypond's notation reference](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.25/Documentation/notation/rehearsal-marks) suggests looking to `scm/translation-functions.scm` for inspiration, and in there I found `format-mark-generic` accepts an `oval` option.  It helps with the vertical space, but it's still not pretty:

```
\set Score.rehearsalMarkFormatter = #(format-mark-generic '(numbers oval))
```

[image]

The original score deals with this by just using a box with a large-rounded corners.
I'd like to use that same approach.

[image]

The closest I can get is by using `\rounded-box`, but the `corner-radius` seems to max-out at 2 and it would be nice if it was 1/2 the height of the box.

```
#(define (format-mark-roundbox-numbers number context)                          
   #{ \markup \override #'(corner-radius . 2) \rounded-box #(format-mark-numbers number context) #})

\set Score.rehearsalMarkFormatter = #format-mark-roundbox-numbers
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not that 'corner-radius' maxes out at 2. It is limited by half of the shorter side (which should be a circle).

Now the real issue is that the underlying function `rounded-box-stencil` assumes `blot` to be the blot radius, while the actual drawing C++ function `ly:round-filled-box` and `Lookup::round_filled_box` assume that `blot` is the blot **diameter**. These also limit the blot, so `rounded-box-stencil` shouldn’t really need to do so (apart from making inner and outer box the same blot, which can look weird anyway).

So we can simply get rid of that and do

```
#(define (my-rounded-box-stencil stencil thickness padding blot)
  (let* ((xext (interval-widen (ly:stencil-extent stencil 0) padding))
         (yext (interval-widen (ly:stencil-extent stencil 1) padding))
         (min-ext (min (-(cdr xext) (car xext)) (-(cdr yext) (car yext))))
         (ideal-blot blot)
         (ideal-thickness (min thickness (/ min-ext 2)))
         (outer (ly:round-filled-box
                 (interval-widen xext ideal-thickness)
                 (interval-widen yext ideal-thickness)
                 ideal-blot))
         (inner (ly:stencil-in-color
                 (ly:round-filled-box
                  xext yext (- ideal-blot ideal-thickness))
                 "white")))
    (ly:stencil-add outer inner stencil)))

#(define-markup-command (my-rounded-box layout props arg)
  (markup?)
  #:category graphic
  #:properties ((thickness 1)
                (corner-radius 1)
                (font-size 0)
                (box-padding 0.5))
  #:as-string (format #f "[~a]"
                      (markup->string arg #:layout layout #:props props))
  (let ((th (* (ly:output-def-lookup layout 'line-thickness)
               thickness))
        (pad (* (magstep font-size) box-padding))
        (m (interpret-markup layout props arg)))
    (my-rounded-box-stencil m th pad corner-radius)))

#(define-markup-command (wide-dimension layout props mup) (markup?)
   (let* ((m (interpret-markup layout props mup))
          (ext-x (ly:stencil-extent m X))
          (ext-y (ly:stencil-extent m Y))
          (width (interval-length ext-x))
          (height (interval-length ext-y)))
     (if (< width height)
         (ly:make-stencil (ly:stencil-expr m) (interval-widen ext-x (/ (- height width) 2)) ext-y)
         m)))

#(define (format-mark-roundbox-numbers number context)                          
   #{ \markup \override #'(corner-radius . +inf.0) \my-rounded-box \wide-dimension #(format-mark-numbers number context) #})

{
  \set Score.rehearsalMarkFormatter = #format-mark-roundbox-numbers
  \repeat unfold 200 { \mark\default c1 }
}
```

I’ve also added a function that makes sure that the mark is at least as wide as it is high to have single digits circled (rather than using a narrow rectangle).

The result:

[image]